# National visa D

Tags: poland

I am from india and i live in poland. I have polish national visa D on my passport. My visa is valid until 29-11-2016. My girlfriend is from germany. She always come to here and live with me somedays. I want to ask that can i go to germany with this visa and how many days i can stay there?  We both want to marry each other so tell me the right procedure about marriage that where can we get married? In poland or germany? And documents i need?
 Thanks

Comment: We can't help you with the marriage question; try [expatriates.se] instead. For your other question, see the linked Q&A.